# Are there generic types of AnimationController? If not, why?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Flutter newbie here. I am using Tween<Offset> with an AnimationController. And I'm trying to use animateTo() method with a target of type Offset. Is this possible?

Document says:

> animateTo(double target, { Duration duration, Curve curve: Curves.linear }) → TickerFuture
>
> Drives the animation from its current value to target

AnimationController:

```
_controller = AnimationController(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  vsync: this,
);
```

AnimateTo():

```
_controller.animateTo(Offset(0,0))
```

The above line is not correct:

```
The argument type 'Offset' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
```

Are there generic types of AnimationController? If not, why? I know I can use `Tween<Offset>(begin:.., end:..).animate(_controller)`. But looks like animateTo() and similar AnimationController methods are just for a target of type double. This looks confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. *AnimationController* only handle *double*.

The *double* used by *AnimationController* have a different meaning from the *double* used by *Tween*.

*AnimationController* is only about the animation progress, while *Tween* may output one value after many layers of transformations.

As such, not only it is very difficult to convert a transformed value back to the progress it represents, it also suffers from limitations:

Curves. If an *AnimationController* should handle any tweenable object, then it would implicitly support curves too.

The thing is, we can have such curve:

[image]

But this raises an issue. As we can see in the previous gif, after transformed by a curve, we can have multiple time the same value emitted.

In that case, what would be the desired behavior for an `animateTo(X)` if a controller can emit X multiple times?

This wouldn't make sense. As such, *AnimationController* works with nothing but a linear floating value. If we want more complicated behaviors, we have to use different objects.

Comment: Target of AnimationController is about progress. That was I looking for actually. After  seeing it in action with @Mertus's answer, it's very clear. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is this,

```
var _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2));

var _animation = Tween(begin: Offset(0,0), end: Offset(5,5));

_controller.animateTo(0.5);
```

The Tween class is an [Animatable](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/Animatable-class.html) which produces interpolated values for your animation.
the animateTo method gets a value between 0 and 1 (although you can define these bounds yourself in the constructor of AnimationController default values are 0 and 1). For example if you give 0.5 to animateTo method you will animate right to the half way between your offset values.